# How can we use espresso to test an android settings activity with an PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-settings

How can we use espresso *onView* and *perform* in a Settings activity that contains a PreferenceFragment like this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment

Answer (score 2):

The Preferences are in a list so you have to query for the specific preference like this:

```
// Check if is displayed    
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Preference.class)), withKey("prefkey"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

// Perform click
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Preference.class)), withKey("prefkey"))).onChildView(withClassName(is(Switch.class.getName()))).perform(click());
```

I found this article helpful: http://www.winters.nz/2015/05/espresso-for-android-hints-properties.html

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Maybe fix it or remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below logic

```
// Check if it is displayed    
onData(PreferenceMatchers.withKey(context.getResources().getString(R.string.prefkey))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```